# GROUP BY this OR that

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I've got a web app that uses either Facebook ID or Contact # as an entrant identifier. This is because the client doesn't want those without Facebook to miss out on entering (so there's a web app as well as a Facebook app)

So I'm trying to:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) 
FROM `entries_table` 
WHERE is_daily_winner = 2 
GROUP BY fbid OR contact_no 
HAVING COUNT(*) <=4
```

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is selecting entries with `is_daily_winner = 2` is less than or equal to 4 rows per `fbid` or `contact_no`.

Currently I only get one row back, rather than the 3 I was expecting.

What am I doing wrong? or can I even `GROUP BY x OR y` ?

**EDIT:** I'm expanding this question, as I forgot to include another clause.

The `HAVING COUNT(*) <=4` should be across all entries, but I only need to get those entered within the last day.
I've just tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `entries_table` 
WHERE `timestamp` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) IN
  (SELECT * FROM `entries_table` 
   WHERE is_daily_winner = 2 
   GROUP BY fbid 
   HAVING COUNT(*) <=4
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM `entries_table` 
   WHERE is_daily_winner = 2
   GROUP BY contact_no 
   HAVING COUNT(*) <= 4)
```

And I get the error `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: Why don't you create 2 query's to do that and compare the results of both? You can't use OR with GROUP BY.

Comment: You can group by (fbid,contact_no),but this will result considering both columns.If you want separate results of both groups,you have to use two sub queries and making union them.

Comment: okay thanks, I'll research sub queries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS nr FROM `entries_table` 
   WHERE is_daily_winner = 2 
   AND `timestamp` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   GROUP BY fbid 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS nr FROM `entries_table` 
   WHERE is_daily_winner = 2
   AND `timestamp` >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   GROUP BY contact_no 
) sq 
WHERE nr <= 4
```

I changed `UNION` to `UNION ALL`, because `UNION` implies a `DISTINCT`. I don't think, that's what you want (or even need, `UNION ALL` is also faster, because it doesn't have to check if there are duplicate rows).

And note, that selecting `*` and grouping by something is actually bad practice. By grouping and not having aggregate functions on the columns that are not mentioned in the `group by`, random rows are picked for each group to display. Just wanted to mention that.

Comment: Nice, one question: What's `sq` ? (second to last line)

Comment: A subquery needs an alias :)

Answer (score 1):

You can Better use **UNION** like

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) 
   FROM `entries_table` 
   WHERE is_daily_winner = 2 
   GROUP BY fbid
   HAVING COUNT(*) <=4
UNION
SELECT *, COUNT(*) 
   FROM `entries_table` 
   WHERE is_daily_winner = 2 
   GROUP BY contact_no
   HAVING COUNT(*) <=4
```

Comment: I've updated my question, because I now realised I need to get entries within the last day, but `COUNT()` over the whole period.